# ImageView is covering Recyclerview Options when bottom Navigation Bar is Active

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-recyclerview, android-navigation

I have developed an app and it is currently in the BETA testing stage and I am working through bug fixes. This one particular issue has been driving me nuts; the issue I have is that certain android devices have bottom navigation bars, (the particular phone i am having this issue with this the HTC One M9) and this bottom navigation bar is causing the image I have on the view to cover up my Recycler View option.

I have tried all solutions to try and programmatically hide the bottom tool bar but nothing has worked. When I go into settings and hide the bottom navigation bar the display is correct again however I not everyone may be aware/have the 'hide bottom navigation bar' feature and so I wanted to overcome this alignment issue without the user having to make any further customisation.

This is my xml file: **festivals.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:windowTranslucentStatus="false"
                android:statusBarColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:navigationBarColor="@android:color/transparent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/festivals_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="470dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ganesh_red"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the .java file corresponding to the above .xml file: **FestivalsActivity.java**

```
public class FestivalsActivity extends BaseActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapterFestivals.ClickListener {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    //Creating an instance of the adapter object
    private RecyclerViewAdapterFestivals adapter;

    private static final int ITEM_COUNT = 2;

    @Override
    //public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.festivals);

        //This line of code will set the View to full screen without any trimming
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        //This line will forcefully hide the bottom navigation bar on devices that have them
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

        //Setting the orientation to Portrait Only
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        //Calling Activate Toolbar method (with the Back button enabled)
        activateToolBar();

        //Instantiating the recycler view as defined in national_committee
        mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.festivals_recycler_view);

        //Adding item decoration. Recycler view divider
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));

        //Initialising the adapter - Passing in the activity and the getData method
        adapter=new RecyclerViewAdapterFestivals(this, getData());

        //Here passing in the click listener into the Adapter. 'this' signifies that it is the fragment that handles the click listener.
        //This is possible as the on Click Listener interface is being implemented.
        adapter.setClickListener(this);

        //Setting the adapter
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Setting the Layout
        //mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar enough_food it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

        //int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //Creating an array list of information objects that can be passed into the recycler view
    public static List<SubInformation> getData() {

        List<SubInformation> data = new ArrayList<>();

        //String array of text for the recycler view
        String[] text = {"January - June", "July - December"};

        //For loop to go through entire length of the menu string
        for(int i=0; i<ITEM_COUNT; i++){

            data.add(new SubInformation(text[i]));
        }

        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {

    }
}
```

Please find the screenshots below (first with, second one without navigation bar)

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the bottom bar is pushing the ImageView up causing it to cover the second option in the recylerview, I don't want this to happen. I would like the view to display how it does without the bottom Navigation bar even with the bottom bar active. Hope this makes sense. Is this possible?

I think it is something real small i am failing to see.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Add `android:layout_below="@+id/festivals_recycler_view` to your `imageView`. Now image should be always under `July - December` text

Comment: Is it what you expected?

Comment: @piotrek1543 thanks for your prompt reply. I already tried this, but i gave it another go. This just places the recycler view on top of the image view and so there is no image displaying at all, just a blank white space where the image is supposed to be displaying. So no, not what i expected. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: so your recycler is bigger than two elements? I thought that there are only two-three elements :-) I don't see any other choice. You can make smaller image, but then you would have much space on left and right.

Comment: @piotrek1543 correct. There are only 2 elements/rows in the recycler view. Hence I have set the layout_height attribute to the recycler view to be wrap_content. Do you mean i have to change the height attribute size of the recycler view?

Comment: Changing size of the recycler view would be an option, but then you would take smaller screen device, and you would think that no effect, but try with it :-)

Comment: @piotrek1543 i just tried that on the htc One. I don't have the M9 on me right at this moment so will have to get back to you once I have tried it on there. That seems to work on the HTC One. But this doesn't seem the most efficient way. As you mentioned above about the small screen devices, is there a better way to get round this?

Comment: create 4.0 screen emulator and check how it looks on it. If needed create custom thiner toolbar - i don't think you need as wide as standard for it. You can also change height of recycler. Then i f it looks good check on HTC One

Comment: @piotrek1543 your suggestion of changing the recycler view worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: so good to hear that. I added it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

(check comments for more information)

Change size of the `RecyclerView`, I mean take smaller screen device. If you don't have it, please make a 4' screen emulator.  Check how it looks on it.

If needed **create custom thinner toolbar** - i don't think you need as wide as standard for it.

You can also change height of `RecyclerView`. Then if it looks good check on HTC One.

Keep in your mind that there are some screen devices and Android version. As I see your HTC has Lollipop (5.x) version. Check also how it looks on Kitkat and older by creating some more emulators or buying some cheap different screen-sized phones.

Hope it help